# MissingManifestResourceException runtime

Tags: asp.net

Any suggestions on the following error:

```
"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the 
neutral culture.  Make sure "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" 
was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time, 
or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."
```

I added ajax control toolkit to my project....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160959/asp-net-error-with-assembly

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have: **ScriptManager** on your .aspx page.

Note: There is one special requirement when using the controls from the AJAX Control Toolkit. The page must contain a ScriptManager control. The ScriptManager control is responsible for including all of the necessary JavaScript required by the AJAX Control Toolkit controls.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: @Kapil Khandelwal you need green mark for correct answer :)